# How to Show Info About What This Button Does

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am developing a UWP app. I want to show some info about a specific button whenever a user moves the cursor to that button. Just like the below image. I need your help. How can I do this ?
[image]

Comment: Isn't that just a [tooltip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip)?

Comment: If an answer fits your need, you can accept one of them in order to help other people to find an answer quicker the next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tooltip you can see documentation here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip

```
<!-- A button with a simple ToolTip. -->
<Button Content="Button with a simple ToolTip." ToolTipService.ToolTip="Simple ToolTip" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Image ToolTip" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
  <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    // put whatever you want to appear in tooltip here.
  </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you, guys. I will inform you if I can successfully implement this.